# Adding arrays at run-time in 4d numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to make a list of 3d numpy arrays for which I need to make a 4d numpy array and then later append the sub-arrays to it.I saw this method to create empty arrays:

```
numpy.empty(shape, dtype=float, order='C')
```

The problem is,the size of the 3d arrays in each dimension is not fixed.But while making the 4d numpy array,I have to define the shape and dimensions.

Can anyone please provide some information on how this functionality can be achieved.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "the size of the 3d arrays in each dimension is not fixed." what do you mean, exactly? Can you give an example?

Comment: I think he/she means that it is a 3D matrix and the number of rows, columns and frames is not fixed

Comment: I am trying to implement a perceptron model for image classification,in which each image is of different size,for eg:1.)(3,1200,1600) 2.)(3,400,400)

Comment: you have to do preprocessing and bring your images down to one size

Comment: @MohsinBukhari,yes and it's a he,have to update the name

Comment: you can use OpenCV. Let me find you a piece of code to do that. Do you have any problem using anything other than numpy?

Comment: No,the classifier is ready,just the data input is wrong

Comment: is your problem solved? should I put this as an answer?

Comment: @user8586569 you need to normalize your images first and make them all of the same size

Comment: @MohsinBukhari No,which answer?

Comment: @user2314737,how? by OpenCV?

Comment: By making the size same of all the images,won't it change the representation of the image?

Comment: @Saurabh there are many ways to do it, for instance with [skimage.transform.resize`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize)

Comment: `np.empty` is not a clone of list empty, '[]'.  It's an entirely different meaning of 'empty'.  Don't use it for this purpose. There's no such thing as an array without a fixed dimension.

Comment: Similar question about using `np.empty`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014541/how-to-repeatedly-concatenate-numpy-arrays

Comment: The type of the variable after that function is <class 'list'>,I need a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to store 3D numpy arrays in one 3D numpy array if their shape is not same.

You can store this in a simple python list or a set.

However, figuring out from your comments on the question. I think you need to resize your images. For this you can use OpenCV. OpenCV is a library/package for python.

If you choose to use OpenCV, you can do this to resize your images.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

number_of_images = 10000
target_size = [400, 400]

resized_images = np.empty([10000, 400, 400, 3])

for i, img in enumerate(all_images):
    resized_images[i] = cv2.resize(img, target_size)
```

`resized_images` is now a 4D numpy array which contains all your images.

Comment: pl refer to this link:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49017619/systemerror-new-style-getargs-format-but-argument-is-not-a-tuple-while-using-cs)