# SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple while using csv2.resize

Tags: python-3.x, csv, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am new to OpenCV and trying to make the images of different sizes to a fixed size by csv.resize,code:

```
        op1 = 0
        df = pd.read_csv("train2.csv",usecols=['url'])
        tar_size=[28,28]    
        X_train=np.empty([99,28,28,3])
        url_list = [line[:2] for line in r]
        for i in url_list:
                #op = op+1
                (a,b) = i;
                if ("https://" in b or "http://" in b):
                    #try:
                    re1 = urllib.request.urlopen(b)
                    img_read = re1.read()
                    op.append(b)
                    print(op1)
                    f_name = os.path.join(out_dir,'{}.jpeg'.format(a))  
                    pil_image = Image.open(BytesIO(img_read))
                    pil_image_rgb = pil_image.convert('RGB')
                    print(np.array(pil_image_rgb))

                    #Code works fine till here


                    X_train[op1] = cv2.resize(np.array(pil_image_rgb),tar_size)#error
                    op1 = op1+1
                    #except:
                    print("NO")
                else:
                    print("here")
```

The output of np.array(pil_image_rgb):

```
[[[ 80 124 197]
  [ 80 124 197]
  [ 79 123 196]
  ...
  [107 146 211]
  [106 145 210]
  [106 145 212]]

 [[ 78 122 195]
  [ 79 123 196]
  [ 80 124 197]
  ...
  [106 147 213]
  [106 147 213]
  [108 147 214]]

 [[ 78 122 195]
  [ 79 123 196]
  [ 79 123 196]
  ...
  [106 147 209]
  [107 148 210]
  [106 147 209]]

 ...

 [[ 66 114 124]
  [ 65 113 123]
  [ 65 111 124]
  ...
  [ 76 109 114]
  [ 78 111 116]
  [ 77 110 115]]

 [[ 69 113 124]
  [ 68 112 123]
  [ 67 111 124]
  ...
  [ 76 110 112]
  [ 74 108 110]
  [ 75 109 111]]

 [[ 71 115 128]
  [ 71 115 128]
  [ 73 117 130]
  ...
  [254 254 254]
  [255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]]
```

The above output is just of one image,of all the images of different size,I want to make all the images of 28*28*3.

The error is: **SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple**

Can anyone please suggest what might be the error?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: the size has to be a tuple, i.e.`tar_size=(28,28) ` mind the parenthesis

Comment: yes,that worked,thanks